# Transform a Panel in worldspace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, camera, panel

I have got a canvas in world space. A panel is the child of this canvas. 
 I have got another sphere that moves with reference to the MainCamera.

I would like to clamp the image to the Sphere in world space. Following is my code,

```
 public class ClampImage : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public Camera FirstpersonCamera;
        public GameObject panel;

        void Update()
        {
            //get the position of the sphere in the worldspace
            Vector3 spherePosition = FirstpersonCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);
            //assign the world position of the sphere to the image
            panel.transform.position = spherePosition;

        }
    }
```

This script has been hooked to the sphere Gameobject.  Unfortunately, the panel is not moving at all. How do I clamp the panel to the sphere?

Comment: You said it was working earlier

Comment: it works only when canvas is in screenspace overlay :( unfortunately it has to work when canvas is in world space :(

Comment: Sphere position is in screen space because that is what WorldToScreenPoint does, try adding an empty object for where on the sphere you want the panel, and move it there directly, with no conversion

Comment: @TomerShahar could you please explain a bit?

Comment: world to screen space translates x,y,z positions to the x,y that represent the screen of your camera. but your canvas is already in world space.

If the only thing in the canvas is the panel, drag the canvas to the entire canvas to the sphere so that the canvas becomes a child of the sphere. They will move together

Comment: It moves but it is moving in a weird way. It looks small and the ui is choppy

Comment: How do I rotate the panel along with the camera in such a way that it faces me always?

Comment: surely you use the lookat command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it worked with a `Screenspace Overlay` because then your line

```
Vector3 spherePosition = FirstpersonCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);
```

made sense and placed your panel in pixel space coordinates.

---

Now that your Panel is in `Worldspace` you do not want to convert the World-Space position into pixel display space anymore. So simply get rid of this step and rather directly use the world space position you already have

```
//assign the world position of the sphere to the image
panel.transform.position = transform.position;
```

Then to make it always look to the camera you could simply do

```
panel.transform.rotation = FirstPersonCamera.transform.rotation;
```

Or if you want it more correct and not depend on the direction you're looking in you can use

```
panel.transform.LookAt(panel.transform.position + Camera.transform.forward);
```

Since the forward vector of the panel has to actually look exactly away from the camera.

---

In case you want the image have an additional offset e.g. in front of the sphere you could also do

```
panel.transform.position = transform.position - FirstPersonCamera.transform.forward * SomeOffsetInUnits;
```